# Rikaisama to Anki real-time import: Error, current note type does not contain the following field: 'Meaning'

Tags: firefox-extensions, anki

In Rikaisama, when I press the Real-Time Import key, I get this error:

---

[image: Rikaisama real-time import]

---

Even though Anki is open on this deck which definitely has a `Meaning` field:

[image: Anki fields]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem today.

Solution:

- Open the Deck and press "Add" to open the Add dialog
- Select the desired note type and press "Choose"

  - **!!! Important: Do this even if it is already selected !!!**
- Close the add dialog (optional)

-> Import should work now